# UFW firewall still blocking SMB despite adding rules

Tags: samba, firewall, ufw

I have an Ubuntu PC with ufw firewall (GUI version). I have added the preset Samba service, in and out, and even tried adding the ports manually (135-139, 445, UDP and TCP, in and out), but it still blocks samba.

I am trying to access a share on another PC on my LAN. If I disable ufw, it works fine. It must be still blocking something and I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 beta 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

As root, open `/etc/default/ufw`

Look for the line like this:

```
IPT_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_irc nf_nat_irc"
```

Add `nf_conntrack_netbios_ns` to the line so that it looks like this:

```
IPT_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_irc nf_nat_irc nf_conntrack_netbios_ns"
```

Now reload the firewall:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

Comment: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper` is also necessary with newer kernels

Comment: FWIW that will probably fail as the user doesn't have access to that file. Instead, `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper` should work.

Answer (score 41):

Mike's `sudo ufw allow Samba` works like a charm.

I personally prefer restricting to my private subnet, so for others who like the same, use:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 to any app Samba
```

Also, try running `sudo ufw app list` for a list of other apps you can use as short-hand to the required ports (eg. Postfix, OpenSSH, etc). Makes your firewall rules list a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I like to add a "`comment 'passing samba from local'`" (without outer quotes) to the end of the ufw command line as a reminder so that when you do `sudo ufw status numbered` (or whatever) you can see why the rules are there.

Comment: Samba application rules are not installed by default

Answer (score 20):

To allow samba with ufw use the following command

```
sudo ufw allow Samba
```

See the links given to you by other users for additional information.

Comment: Samba application rules are not installed by default

Comment: you can install Samba with `sudo apt install samba`, then you will be able to use the command `sudo ufw allow Samba`

Answer (score 13):

As I found no ufw profile for Samba 4 AD DC I set up my own which worked for me (opens the ports as listed in the [Samba Wiki: Ports for Samba 4 as AD DC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_Port_Usage)) and is easier to manage :

1. Create a new file: **/etc/ufw/applications.d/samba-ad-dc** with the following content

   ```
    [samba-ad-dc]
    title=Samba 4 AD DC
    description=Samba 4 as domain controller
    ports=53|88|135/tcp|137/udp|138/udp|139/tcp|389|445/tcp|464|636/tcp|3268/tcp|3269/tcp|49152:65535/tcp
   ```
2. Now add it to ufw with one of the following commands:

   - `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.192.0/24 to any app samba-ad-dc` if you want to only allow it on your 192.168.1.0/24 network
   - `sudo ufw allow samba-ad-dc` if you want to allow it for every network

If you enter `sudo ufw status verbose` it will output something like the following

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
...
53 (samba-ad-dc)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
88 (samba-ad-dc)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
135/tcp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
137/udp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
138/udp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
139/tcp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
389 (samba-ad-dc)          ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
445/tcp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
464 (samba-ad-dc)          ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
636/tcp (samba-ad-dc)      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
3268/tcp (samba-ad-dc)     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
3269/tcp (samba-ad-dc)     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
49152:65535/tcp (samba-ad-dc) ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use logging to find out if you're blocking a port that should not be blocked.

```
tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

Some extra information in case you havened tried it already:
[ufw manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/ufw.8.html) , [ufw wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall?action=show&redirect=UbuntuFirewall)

Comment: Helped me. The client used the external IPv6 address in my case so the allow rules were not working to my surprise.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Here's what I suggest: After installing Gufw, make sure you log out of your account and then log back in.

It worked for me.

In general, whenever you have a problem with software you just installed, try the above suggestion first.

You will be surprised as to how often it cures the problem.