# Windows VirtualBox can't browse network

Tags: virtualbox, samba, ufw

I'm running Windows XP as a VirtualBox guest OS under Ubuntu 11.10, and I can't browse the Windows network. It seems like I can connect to some specific network shares, maybe only ones that are already mapped to drives.

If I disable `ufw`, it all works fine, and when I enable it again, the network browsing continues to work. I tried looking at `/var/log/ufw.log` and saw it blocking port 138. When I allowed that port, then I saw it blocking port 137.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/36646/3986), and it led me to [bug 360975](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/360975). The bug originally asked for  both `nf_conntrack_pptp` and `nf_conntrack_netbios_ns` to be added to the defaults, but in [comment 11](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/360975/comments/11), Jamie decided not to include `nf_conntrack_pptp` in the fix.

I tried adding it in, and it seemed to solve my problem, but then the problem came back.

How can I let the Windows guest OS browse the local network?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the VirtualBox network settings from NAT to bridged adapter solved the problem. It continued to work after I removed the `nf_conntrack_pptp` module, so I guess that was irrelevant.